# How can we explain this very weird behaviour with file:/// URI hyperlinks in documents on MacOS?

Tags: macos, finder, hyperlink, uri

It is useful to be able to create a hyperlink within MacOS text documents that link to other text documents on the same drive of the same computer.

Within [Bean](https://bean-osx.com/Bean.html), the free Mac word-processor I use, I find this can be done by inserting a [file URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) into the hyperlink in a Bean text document, like this for example:

`file:///Users/XXX/Documents/Test.rtf`

Here **XXX** is your Mac home folder name, and **Test.rtf** is a text document that you have created (with Bean say) and placed in your Documents folder. In principle this hyperlink can open Test.rtf.

However, if within a Bean text document you create a hyperlink, and paste in the link: **file:///Users/XXX/Documents/Test.rtf** you find this hyperlink will not work initially. It will not open the Test.rtf document when you click on the link, even though the URI syntax is correct.

But you can fix this problem if in Finder you go to the Test.rtf file itself, copy its filename "Test.rtf" text directly from the file in Finder, and then edit your original hyperlink to delete the "Test.rtf" text from the end, and paste in the "Test.rtf" text you just copied from the Test.rtf file.

If you do this, you will now find this hyperlink starts working! The hyperlink will now successfully open the Test.rtf document when you click on that hyperlink.

This behaviour is weird! I am not sure if it is an issue in Bean, or in MacOS.

I have found that the file:/// URI format is able to open  .txt, .rtf, .rtfd, .doc and .html files (but not pdf files) in hyperlinks in Bean text documents, but only if you paste in the filename that was copied directly from the file itself.

How can we explain this weird behaviour?

Unfortunately I found the file:/// format does not seem to be able to open documents at all in TextEdit or Pages.

Comment: Couldn't this be related to App sandboxing?

Comment: That is an interesting thought, it might be I guess. Though I tried just now giving Bean all the relevant access permissions in System Prefs > Security & Privacy, but to no avail. Usually when a Mac app needs more access permissions, MacOS will place a dialog box on the screen informing you of this, and giving you the option of granting permissions.